# Left side of jquery dialog is off screen when the window is smaller than the dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jquery ui dialog, if the window is smaller in width than the dialog, then the dialog appears but the left side is off-screen. Is there any way I can make it go off-screen to the right instead so that I always see the whole left side?

Edit: It seems a lot of people don't understand what I'm asking. It has nothing to do with setting the position of the dialog to center. That has already been done.

Comment: Did you search Google for something like _jQuery ui dialog align center_? The **first hit** I got was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839702/how-can-i-position-my-jquery-dialog-to-center

Comment: The question is how do you initialize your dialog???

Comment: I already have the dialog position set to center.

Comment: If people aren't understanding what you're asking, perhaps you need to clarify it better and provide a code example of what you've done, what's not working and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try setting using co-ordinates of existing DIV as follows:

```
$('#dialogDiv').dialog( "option", "position",{my: "left top",at: "left bottom", of: "#referenceDiv"});
```