# How to center my pop-up form vertically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a pop-up and I want to center it. Till now I have been giving margin-top. But I guess, this is not the best way to do it.

In my case, there is a link and when it is clicked a pop-up appears, which should be at the center of the page.

*Note :  I want to center the pop-up vertically. I have already centered the pop-up horizontally by using the bootstrap grid system.*

Comment: @WisdmLabs had tried

Comment: @SuhailGupta Try This - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/render/EZkxOcZcbt) and http://www.bootply.com/LzOGs3m5Hw

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are already including jQuery UI with your project (this is definitely not a reason to add it), but if you are - try using Dialog and there is already [an answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839702/how-can-i-position-my-jquery-dialog-to-center) about centering it.